# Force PTY allocation in ssh_config

Tags: ssh, ssh-config

To run interactive programs remotely one should use `ssh -t <host>`. But this `-t` option also has drawbacks so it's not good to use it on non-interactive programs.

My problem is: I have several machines. Some of them are for interactive programs and others for non-interactive ones. So I must remember exactly which ones need `-t`. Is it possible to add this in `~/.ssh/config` so I don't have to remember it?

Basically what I want is this:

```
Host interactive
    HostName example.com
    User user
    Option "-t"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The option you're looking for is `RequestTTY`. From the ssh_config man page:

> **RequestTTY**
>   Specifies whether to request a pseudo-tty for the session. The argument may be one of: `no' (never request a TTY), `yes' (always request a TTY when standard input is a TTY), `force' (always request a TTY) or `auto' (request a TTY when opening a login session). This option mirrors the **-t** and **-T** flags for ssh(1).

`force` is equivalent to `-tt`, and `yes` is equivalent to `-t`

```
Host interactive
    HostName example.com
    User user
    RequestTTY yes
```